# Get NetLogo widgets in headless mode

Tags: netlogo

I need to get the list of all defined widgets in a nlogo script in headless mode. I basically need to the targeted variables and the default values. But I just find private methods in the API to achieve this (https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.x/src/main/org/nlogo/headless/HeadlessModelOpener.scala#L136-L234). Is there a public method from the API to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you just open the model first and then look in `interfaceGlobals`?

Comment: What do you mean "open the model" ?

Comment: I mean call the `open` method in `HeadlessWorkspace`.

Comment: Well, I do not see any method interfaceGlobals in the HeadlessWorspace class: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/scaladoc/#org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace ... ?

Comment: the path from HeadlessWorkspace is `.world.program.interfaceGlobals` (if you're using Java not Scala, you'll probably need to sprinkle some `()`'s in there)

Comment: Well, I parsed it manually because it is too difficult to deal with a program in scala 2.9. Do you plan to upgrade it in 2.11 soon ? Thanks for helping anyway

Comment: Yes, the next major release (codenamed "hexy", version number undetermined) will be Scala 2.11 based.

Comment: An other issue related to this: how can I get the value of a given patches-own. I can only get the patches-own names (with .word.program.patchesOwn()) but I don't know how to get their values.

Comment: Please open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Horn solved this by parsing through the .nlogo file in his NetTango project. If you're okay with that, take a look at his [Model.java load() method](https://github.com/michael-horn/NetTango/blob/master/java/ntango/Model.java#L80-L105), and [initSlider(), initSwitch(), and initPlot() methods](https://github.com/michael-horn/NetTango/blob/master/java/ntango/Model.java#L80-L105). I don't remember the exact relative line location of default value for the other widget types, but if you open a .nlogo file in a text editor, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. It is the kind of solution I wanted to use in last option. I would rather use the official API so that the parser is stable in case of API change. But if there is no other solution through the API, I will use this manual parsing of the nlogo file.